# Finding the minimum number of functional teams needed to do repetitive tasks

Tags: planning, ms-project, resource-planning

I have a Project Plan in MS Project, its a construction project which has repetitive tasks and multiple gangs.
For example:

- Building 1

  - Strip
  - Clean
  - Paint
  - Varnish
- Building 2

  - Strip
  - Clean
  - Paint
  - Varnish
- Building 3

  - Strip
  - Clean
  - Paint
  - Varnish
- Building 4

  - Strip
  - Clean
  - Paint
  - Varnish

Now I have 4 Paint Gangs (PG1, PG2, PG3 & PG4) currently I assign them in leapfrog order, so

- Building 1 = PG1
- Building 2 = PG2
- Building 3 = PG3
- Building 4 = PG4
- Building 5 = PG1
  etc...

The problem is that should I wish to reduce the number of Paint Gangs to see if the project still finishes on time, currently I apply a filter to the task list to display only 'Paint' tasks I then highlight the resource column & predecessors column and delete them. 
I then select the resource column next to each building's paint task and select the paint gang that's next in the order PG1,PG2,PG3,PG4,PG1,PG2,PG3,PG4 but obviously this takes a lot of time and then linking them back up.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: If you have 4 painting groups then buildings 1 through 4 should be able to be done simultaneously. I'm not sure why you are linking (and then unlinking) the tasks.  I'd assign the teams, look for overallocations and work from there.  If all buildings are scheduled for the same time, in your scenario above - only painting gang 1 would be overallocated.

Comment: @JulieS Sorry I didn't explain clearly, buildings 1-4 **would** be done simultaneously like you suggest, the tasks are linked based on the gangs so all the PG1 tasks are linked etc... so buildings 5 painting wouldn't start until building 1 painting was finished. The problem is assigning the gangs and then linking them for 300 buildings is a long job, I'm thinking maybe I'm going the wrong way about it.

Comment: The purists (and I am not one) would say that you should only create links between tasks that are driven by the TASK - not by resources.  So, within each building there should be links between Strip, Clean, Paint, and Varnish as there are logical relationships between those tasks.  Do not link the buildings - assign the resources and then look for overallocations in the resources.  If you want to link Building 1 to Building 5, I'd suggest using some of the spare Flag fields to flag tasks that you have linked because of resource overallocations.  For example set Flag1 to "yes" for PG1 links.

Comment: @JulieS , The reason the painting is linked by Task & Resource is that I need to know how many Paint Gangs are required for the job. the only way I know of doing this is the way I explained, by leapfrogging PG1->4, PG1->4 etc... but adding or removing Paint Gangs takes a long time to complete, thats why I get the feeling I am missing something.

The only other way I could think of doing it, was to take the number of buildings, divide it by the No of Paint Gangs and then batch allocate them PG1 do Buildings 1-75 inclusive, but the building painting has to be done in order.

Comment: I'm not sure why adding or removing Gangs is taking so long.  If you use resource leveling (as I suggested) you add or remove and re-level.  Use priorities to tell Project which buildings are more "important".

Comment: I've done some more playing around and can get it to work quite nicely without the linking and unlinking you seem to be doing.
All buildings (8 in my experiment) are set to start on the same day.  I have set buildings 1-4 with a priority (add the field and use the fill down command) of 999.  The next 4 are are 900.  Paint gang 1 is assigned (using the assign resources dialog) to the tasks in building 1 and 5.  Paint gang 2 is assigned to 2 and 6, Paint 3 to 3 and 7, and Paint gang 4 to 4 and 8.  I level Paint gang 1 - it delays building 2 to following the end of Building 1.

Comment: Now I discover I only have 3 paint crews - I've lost paint crew 4 - so that crew needs to be replaced on two Buildings B4 and B8.  On building 4 I replace them with Crew 1 (using the replace command in Assign resources).  Crew 1 is now overallocated between B1 and B4.  I need to decide if I want building 1, then Building 4, then building 5 done.  Adjust the priorities as needed and relevel.  I am not linking nor unlinking and I am only replacing resources where needed.  Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

### Calculating "Time to Complete" Kanban-Style

I'm not sure if this can be done in MS Project or not, but it seems that what you really are trying to do is determine (in a Kanban-like fashion) how much time you would need to **empty a job queue** assuming some variable number of teams. You would normally do this by calculating *throughput* and *cycle lead time*, and then applying those figures to the size of your input queue.

Consider an example where *throughput* is the average amount of time it takes for a paint task to move from "started" to "finished," and *average_lead_time* is the time a paint job spends in the input queue before the job is started. The formula might look like this:

```
time_to_complete =   
    (paint_jobs_in_queue / (paint_gangs * throughput)) + 
    (average_lead_time * paint_jobs_in_queue)
```

This formula is based on the idea that painting jobs are all similarly-sized, and that each Paint Gang's throughput is within two standard deviations of the mean. You may need to use a more complex formula if these assumptions don't hold true for your project.

Comment: Your answer makes sense, but is there any way to reflect this in MS Project. I removed 1 painting gang yesterday and it took me around 2 hours to do, the task is task dependant but only dependant on the previous painting job that gang was on.

Comment: The painting time is the same across all buildings, currently for my Paint Gangs I have 4 'waterfalls' in my wbs, 1 per Paint Gang, I've been banging my head trying to think of a more efficient way to do this but I can't come up with any ideas.

Comment: Are you sure the formula is correct? If I take *throughput* as "time per job", then you need to multiply it by the number of jobs to get a total time, not divide the number of jobs by it.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Assume 10 jobs, 4 gangs, and each gang can do 1 paint job per day. `2.5 days = 10 jobs / (4 gangs * 1 day per job)` seems right to me, plus lead time; however, *adding* average lead time of `5 days = ((5 * 0) + (5 * 1 day)) * 10 jobs` may or my not yield a sensible value for your work process, but would account for setup/teardown processes and moving buildings if such things impact your schedule. You might simply break out the second portion into a completely separate metric if that's more useful. YMMV.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau But no...I'm not absolutely, positively sure the math is correct. I simply offered it s a starting point. Corrections, suggestions, and worked examples are welcome.

Comment: @CodeGnome: Assuming 10 jobs, 4 gangs and 2 days per job: `1.25 day = 10 jobs / (4 gangs * 2 day per job)` seems wrong to me. If I completely ignore lead time, a better starting point might be `RoundUp(paint_jobs_in_queue / paint_gangs) * average_time_per_job_per_gang`. The rounding is there on the assumption that it is not possible to allocate multiple gangs to the same job.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I think I slipped off the rails trying to decompose per-process throughput into per-team and per-gang throughput. What about `(paint_jobs_in_queue * (team_throughput_per_day / paint_gangs))`? Lead time is generally per-process too, and is impacted by the WIP limit, so it has similar problems. We can move this to chat if you think it's worth delving further.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to assign the gangs to a resource type.  Then specify the resource type to the tasks for each building.  It should then be possible to level your resources. Setting date limits on start and end dates can help order assignment to buildings.

As long as you don't end up with things on a critical path, you can calculate the number of gangs required manually.

- Sum the number of days effort.
- Divide by the number of work days until all work needs to be completed.
- Round up to the next number.

For instance:

- 231 days effort.
- 68 days until completion
- Calculates to 3.4 gangs.
- Round up yeilds 4 gangs.

Then you can use the project software to allocate the teams to particular buildings.  Watch out for unexpected idle time, or resource overloading.  Holidays and other events can cause unexpected deviations from planned activity.